# Discord.py | Mysqlx not working in heroku

Tags: python, mysql, database, heroku, discord

Im trying to connect my DB for my discord bot.

I decided to use mysqlx module for python but when I run the code in heroku raises an error.

I'm using github for deployment method

- Version checked.
- It is locally working.
- Checked `get_session` definition in local.

`get_session` definition in local:

```
def get_session(*args, **kwargs):
    """Creates a Session instance using the provided connection data.

    Args:
        *args: Variable length argument list with the connection data used
               to connect to a MySQL server. It can be a dictionary or a
               connection string.
        **kwargs: Arbitrary keyword arguments with connection data used to
                  connect to the database.

    Returns:
        mysqlx.Session: Session object.
    """
    settings = _get_connection_settings(*args, **kwargs)
    return Session(settings)
```

I have another app hosted in Heroku that uses the same module and deployment method and works perfectly. I can't understand why it doesn't work in this heroku.

Heroku error:

```
File "/app/bot.py", line 25, in <module>
session = mysqlx.get_session({
AttributeError: module 'mysqlx' has no attribute 'get_session'
```

The code:

```
import mysqlx

session = mysqlx.get_session({
"host": "",
"port": 3306,
"user": "",
"password": ""
})
```

Comment: What is `mysqlx`? Do you mean [this library](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlx/)? I've never heard of it, and [its Homepage link](https://gitee.com/summry/mysqlx/mysqlx) goes to a 404. Looks sketchy to me. Why aren't you using a more popular library?

Comment: I'm not familiarized with databases, `mysql.connector` raises a syntax error that i can't solve so at the beginning mysqlx was helpful but now it doesn't.